# How to get BibTeX to provide in-text parenthetical citation with full name of author?

Tags: bibtex, citing, article

I am trying to format a bibliography in `LaTeX`. Here is the `BibTeX` syntax:

```
@online{levada,
    author = "Levada Center",
    title = "Political Trust",
    url  = "https://www.levada.ru/en/2020/10/22/political-trust-3/",
    addendum = "(Accessed: 07.06.2021)",
    keywords = "latex,knuth"
```

When I use `\citep{levada}` in my text, I get the following parenthetical citation: (Center, 2020). Is there a way to modify my `BibTeX` syntax so as to get (Levada Center, 2020) as my parenthetical citation?

Comment: put the author in two braces: `author = {{Levada Center}},`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked well.